# MapReduce and Hadoop: what kinds of problems are they good at solving?

Tags: parallel-processing, hadoop

As I understand it already, it seems that both have similar functions (except that MapReduce is proprietary to Google, while Hadoop is open-source).

I was wondering, not "how they work", but rather some good examples on the usual kinds of problems they are deployed to solve. I know that they take parallel inputs (or makes them parallel). Are MapReduce and Hadoop used for generic parallel computations, or does a problem need to be more specific to be a better fit for the two models?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [Hadoop MapReduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/). :)

"Uses" for MapReduce (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)):

> MapReduce is useful in a wide range of applications including:
>   distributed grep, distributed sort, web link-graph reversal,
>   term-vector per host, web access log stats, inverted index
>   construction, document clustering, machine learning, and statistical
>   machine translation. Moreover, the MapReduce model has been adapted to
>   several computing environments like multi-core and many-core systems,
>   desktop grids, volunteer computing environments, dynamic cloud
>   environments, and mobile environments.
>
> At Google, MapReduce was used
>   to completely regenerate Google's index of the World Wide Web.
>
> It replaced the old ad hoc programs that updated the index and ran the
>   various analyses.

Check out [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PoweredBy) for a huge list of organizations using Hadoop, and what they're using it for.

A few of the "B"s, for example:

> • **BabaCar**  ◦ 4 nodes cluster (32 cores, 1TB).
>
> ◦ We use Hadoop for searching and analysis of millions of rental
>   bookings.
>
> • **Baidu** - the leading Chinese language search engine  ◦ Hadoop used to
>   analyze the log of search and do some mining work on web page database
>
> ◦ We handle about 3000TB per week
>
> ◦ Our clusters vary from 10 to 500 nodes
>
> ◦ Hypertable is also supported by Baidu
>
> • **Beebler**  ◦ 14 node cluster (each node has: 2 dual core CPUs, 2TB
>   storage, 8GB RAM)
>
> ◦ We use hadoop for matching dating profiles
>
> • **Benipal Technologies** - Outsourcing, Consulting, Innovation  ◦ 35
>   Node Cluster (Core2Quad Q9400 Processor, 4-8 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD)
>
> ◦ Largest Data Node with Xeon E5420*2 Processors, 64GB RAM, 3.5 TB HDD
>
> ◦ Total Cluster capacity of around 20 TB on a gigabit network with
>   failover and redundancy
>
> ◦ Hadoop is used for internal data crunching, application development,
>   testing and getting around I/O limitations

Comment: WOW thanks! Btw, when these massive data crunchings occur, such as Beebler and Google's search engine, I guess what I was wondering was, do you know what information is being "mapped", and then what's being "reduced"? :)